# Make a list of files that contain just numbers as the filename in Windows

Tags: windows, filenames

I have a large number of files on multiple hard drives, some of which are just in a format like 1.mkv
Sometimes that 1 is actually multiple digits, but in all cases (that I'm currently looking for) it is just digits before the extension.
I did search and try a few options that were similar to my question, but in all cases I ended up with results that exceeded what I'm actually looking for.
It would be a bonus if there was a way to search multiple drives (searching multiple directories is easy), rather than having to enter the command or use a batch file with each drive one at a time.
If I have omitted any necessary information, please let me know and I'll post it as soon as I can.
Hoping to get at least one good (great?) answer in short order.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the free
[Everything by voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/).

Install the product, ensure that your disks are marked as indexed and
give it some time to process the disks.

To search, enable the menu entry *Search > Enable Regex*, then enter
the following search expressions.

For file-names that have only numbers without an extension:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

For file-names that have only numbers and an extension:

```
^[0-9]+\..{1,3}$
```

The resulting list is displayed instantly.
You may export it to a file by using the menu entry
*File > Export...*